# Rectangle Bars are not showing up as different colors or at all

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, ivalueconverter

I want the bars to show as a different color based on the rating. I would also like if my convert would actual work like it is intended instead of giving me an error.

My converter is not working I am not able to see the color change based of the Rating Binding?

RatingPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RatingAgency.Views.EventsPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RatingAgency.ViewModels"
             BackgroundColor="DarkBlue">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:RatingViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:RatingConverter x:Key="RatingColorChange" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
          <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource Bars}">
            <Rectangle VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2,0,0,0" WidthRequest="5" HeightRequest="5"         Fill="{Binding Rating, Converter={StaticResource RatingColorChange}}"/> 
            <Rectangle VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2,0,0,0" WidthRequest="5" HeightRequest="10" Fill="{Binding Rating, Converter={StaticResource RatingColorChange}}"/>
             <Rectangle VerticalOptions="End" Margin="2,0,0,0" WidthRequest="5" HeightRequest="15" Fill="{Binding Rating, Converter={StaticResource RatingColorChange}}"/>
          </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

RatingViewModel

namespace RatingAgency.ViewModels
{
public class RatingViewModel: ViewModelBase
{

```
    public List<Event> Events
    {
        get { return events; }
        set { events = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public RatingViewModel()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rating Convert to color
    /// </summary>
    public class RatingConverter : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                double rate;
                double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out rate);
                if (rate >= 66)
                {
                    return Brush.Green;
                }
                else if (rate >= 60)
                {
                    return Brush.Green;
                }
                else if (rate >= 54.5)
                {
                    return Brush.Orange;
                }
                else if (rate <= 54.3)
                {
                    return Brush.Red;
                }
            }
            return Brush.Red;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }  
  }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XLS0414 The type 'local:RatingConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   MauiService C:\Users\johnd\Documents\MauiService\Views\RatingPage.xaml  12

Comment: your VM does not have a property named `Rating`.  You also do not have your converter declared correctly

Comment: your XAML refers to `EventsViewModel` but the code you posted is for `RatingViewModel`

Comment: I fixed the error. to answer your first question about rating. I am pulling that data from the server.

Comment: Dont put your converter inside a class put it inside a namespace.#locationmatters